# How to remove white space to validate value using watch in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hook-form

> i would like to disable the continue button if values is empty, but
> with this if we enter space it is validating and enabling the button.
> i am also trimming the value.

```
 const disableContinue = () => {
    if (!watch('firstName') || !watch('lastName')) return true;
    if (!watch('nameChangeReason')) return true;
    if (watch('nameChangeReason') === 'Other') {
      if (!watch('nameChangeOtherReason')) return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
```

> textField component
>
> <TextField
> variant="outlined"
> inputRef={typeof register === 'function' ? register(name) : ref}
> required={required}
> value={typeof value === 'string' ? value?.trimStart() : value}
> name={name} />

Comment: did you try this ? if(stringValue.trim().length){} So this will check if the length is a positive integer, So the condition will be truthy if the value is greater than 0 else it will be falsy, and you can return. Kindly post what are the values that you are checking at least a hard coded dummy value for the check variables.